# calculate user stats with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My user activity log looks something like this:

Id, Username, Date

I need to calculate the total number of entries per day, and most active user of that day for the last 10 days.

```
//pseudo code
from entry in data.UserLogs
group by entry.Date == each day
select username of most active user, count(Id)
```

Im new to LINQ and SQL can someone help me complete this query?

Comment: can you clarify: is the `Date` column a *date*, or a *date and time* ?

Comment: the primary grouping is probably just `group by entry.Date.Date`, then - the really problematic thing is getting the most active user per day *at the same time*. Frankly, I think I'd be dropping to TSQL for that - that isn't a trivial query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. Just drop it into LINQPad to see it in action

```
void Main()
{
    var logs = new List<UserLog>
        {
            new UserLog { Id= 1, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Username = "cburgdorf"},
            new UserLog { Id= 2, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Username = "cburgdorf"},
            new UserLog { Id= 3, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Username = "cburgdorf"},
            new UserLog { Id= 4, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Username = "Mister Foo"},
            new UserLog { Id= 5, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Username = "Mister Foo"},
            new UserLog { Id= 6, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Bar"},
            new UserLog { Id= 7, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Bar"},
            new UserLog { Id= 8, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "cburgdorf"},
            new UserLog { Id= 9, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Foo"},
            new UserLog { Id= 10, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Foo"},
            new UserLog { Id= 11, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Foo"},
            new UserLog { Id= 12, Date = new DateTime(2012,1,2), Username = "Mister Bar"}
        };

    logs
        .OrderByDescending (l => l.Date)
        .GroupBy (log => log.Date)      
        .Select (log => log
                        .GroupBy (l => l.Username)
                        .Select (l => new 
                        {
                            Count = l.Count (),
                            Value = l.FirstOrDefault (),
                        })
                        .OrderBy (l => l.Count).Last ())
        .Select (log => new 
        {
            Date = log.Value.Date,
            Count = log.Count,
            Username = log.Value.Username
        })
        .Take(10)
        .Dump();

        //In LINQPad use Dump() to see the results:
        /*
            logs
                .OrderByDescending (l => l.Date)
                .GroupBy (log => log.Date)      
                .Select (log => log
                                .GroupBy (l => l.Username)
                                .Select (l => new 
                                {
                                    Count = l.Count (),
                                    Value = l.FirstOrDefault (),
                                })
                                .OrderBy (l => l.Count).Last ())
                .Select (log => new 
                {
                    Date = log.Value.Date,
                    Count = log.Count,
                    Username = log.Value.Username
                })
                .Take(10)
                .Dump();
        */


}

class UserLog
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
}


The result is:

    02.01.2012 00:00:00 | 3 | Mister Foo 
    01.01.2012 00:00:00 | 3 | cburgdorf
```

Comment: The question was tagged [tag:sql] too so you may have to consider whether if he's using LINQ to SQL when answering. You used LINQ to Objects here and not all methods are supported. Fortunately I think you're safe here as all methods that you used would be supported.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not sure if this would translate into SQL when using the EntityFramework or LinqToEntities. And if so, how would it perform? It's hard to tell really and also depends on the backend. I run into a lot of "bla bla not supported exceptions" for Oracle backends for instance where as on SQL Server the same query translates fine. This is a pain in the arse at times...

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work.  This will select the top users from the past 10 most recent days.

```
var query =
   (from userLog in data.UserLogs
    group userLog.UserName by userLog.Date.Date into usersPerDate
    orderby usersPerDate.Key descending
    let topUsers =
        from user in usersPerDate
        group 1 by user into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new
        {
            UserName = g.Key,
            Count = count,
        }
    select topUsers.First()).Take(10);
```